# Flask SocketIO auto-reload is not working (on code change/development)

Tags: flask, werkzeug, flask-socketio

Auto reloader (on code change) works fine using app.run/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 8080.

However as soon as I add flask_socketio to the mix it stops working.

E.g. bringing in:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
socketio = SocketIO(app, path='/kpi/socket.io')
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Gunicorn==19.8.1
inotify==0.2.9
pymysql==0.7.2
flask-socketio==3.0.1
eventlet==0.23.0
socketIO-client==0.7.2
```

I do get "* Restarting with stat" in the logs, same as I would if I was typically running flask.

Extraneous info: this is running in a docker container where I have a compose file for dev where I run the dev mode, and have an env variable for FLASK_DEBUG=1. Using nginx to proxy the rest to port 80 then I server that up to another local port. This all works fine and dandy until I add socketio.

Comment: Trying to force the fallback werkzeug by using async_mode='threading'. Which it should fallback to, but that puts docker into a restart loop with: "WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance" in the logs.

Comment: Are you doing the monkey patching for eventlet? The reloader is a fairly complex piece of code, it is unlikely to work under eventlet without monkey patching.

Comment: @Miguel Doing no monkey patching for eventlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending up doing this:

Running this in dev (this brings in the werkzeug debugger for wsgi)

```
# TODO run this only in dev
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
app.debug = True
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, evalex=True)
```

Then use supervisord and run uwsgi instead including the flag

```
--py-autoreload 1
```

Those both return the functionality I want in development. Just need to make them only run in dev mode now and I'm good.