# Flask-SocketIO: Background task is started twice in reloader mode

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

I'm trying to use background tasks with flask-socketio and run into two problems:

1. when in reloader mode, the background task is started twice
2. when changing the code, flask reloads but the background tasks are not killed

My code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import random

application = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(application, async_mode='eventlet')
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

def background_thread():
    print('starting backgound task')
    thread_id = random.randint(1,100)
    while True:
        print(f'background thread {thread_id}')
        socketio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('--------------------')
    socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)
    socketio.run(application, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Output:

```
python application.py
--------------------
starting backgound task
background thread 26
 * Restarting with stat
--------------------
starting backgound task
background thread 59
background thread 26
 * Detected change in '/Users/philipp/code/nifmap/application.py', reloading
background thread 26
background thread 59
background thread 26
background thread 59
```

When I then hit `^C` then *one* background task is killed, but not the other. This happens only when I do `debug=True`. How can I start the background task so that it's only started once and then it's killed upon reload?

The same happens when using gevent, starting with `async_mode='eventlet'` and doing:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Versions:

```
eventlet==0.33.0
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.1
Flask-WTF==0.15.1
greenlet==1.1.2
python-engineio==4.3.0
python-socketio==5.5.0
websocket-client==1.2.3
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [many](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/567) [people](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/617) [having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179369/flask-socketio-auto-reload-is-not-working-on-code-change-development) run into the same problem and reading [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/617#issuecomment-357485674) from the author of Flask-SocketIO:

> It appears that the reloader does not play nice with eventlet

I gave up on auto reload and instead start Flask without the reloader

```
socketio.run(application, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

and use [entr](https://github.com/eradman/entr) to detect file changes:

```
ls *.py | entr -r python application.py
```